# Can't toggle off block comments in VSCode

Tags: formatting, comments, editor, visual-studio-code

In basically any language, like css/scss/js I can select a block of text and use the `editor.action.blockComment` action to surround the text with `/* */`, and that works fine, but to remove it I have to select the comment EXACTLY and activate the command again. I should be able to just put the caret anywhere inside the commented section and hit the key and it will be uncommented but that just puts another comment inside it. I even tried it in Sublime and it uncomments it perfectly as long as the caret is inside the commented section.

Please help! What am I doing wrong? There's no way that’s just the way it is.

Thanks in advance!

~Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the VSCode team.

As of VSCode 1.9, what you describe is the expected behavior of toggle block comment. If you would like to see this improved, [please open a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) and we'll take a look. [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9311) already describes a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it made things more awkward that way but if that's how you guys designed it then you probably know best. Thanks again for the quick response!